# Running SVGO from PHP doens't work with MAMP

Tags: php, unix, permissions, file-permissions

I want to run https://github.com/svg/svgo from PHP but have some problems with the permissons.

My Example App:

```
root
 -- svgo.php
 -- svgfiles
  -- test.svg
 -- node_modules
    -- svgo
      -- bin
        --svgo
```

My PHP Script:

```
<?php
  exec("node_modules/svgo/bin/svgo svgfiles/test.svg -o svgfiles/test.min.svg");
?>
```

When I run on the CLI "php svgo.php" is creates the test.min.svg file, but when I access "localhost/svgo.php" with my MAMP installation it does nothing. I also gave the path "svgfiles" permissons 777.

Comment: What happens if you put `echo` before the `exec`? Maybe it may tell you why it's failing

Comment: the echo will be outputted.

If I echo the return of the exec on the command line it will print the result like 

"test.svg:
Done in 42 ms!
8.104 KiB - 40.5% = 4.824 KiB"

on localhost the echo from exec is empty... no error or else...

Comment: Try running `echo exec("ls");` to ensure you are actually in the correct directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly tell `node` to run the `svgo` library. And use the full path to the binaries.

Example:

`exec("/absolute/path/to/node /absolute/path/to/svgo [options] [args]");`